# What's the easiest way to bring up a MACLISP REPL on modern machines?

Tags: lisp

I'd like to bring up an old (pre-1975) LISP REPL so I can type things in and see how it behaves. MACLISP would be good but I'm open to other, similar LISPs, even as far back as LISP 1.5.

What's the fastest an easiest way to do this? Does anybody run a web page with a REPL? Or is there a package available (preferably that can run under Linux) with all the setup work already done? Or do I need to go as far as installing and configuring SIMH and software for it? If the last, what are the simplest steps to do this?

Answer (score 6):

#### PDP-10 MACLISP (mid-80s version)

[Lars Brinkhoff](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/142/lars-brinkhoff) runs a public ITS system on `its.pdp10.se`
(telnet protocol on port 10003) which has MACLISP available, though
it's a mid-1980s version. You can log in and use it as follows.

Below, `…` indicates elided output text, `^Z` is <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>,
and lines containing your input (sometimes preceeded by a prompt) are
indicated with `»` at the left-hand margin. Expressions are evaluated
as soon as you type the closing parenthesis.

```
» $ telnet its.pdp10.se 10003
  Connected to the KA-10 simulator MTY device, line 2
» ^Z
  TT ITS.1648. DDT.1547.
…
» :LOGIN JMCCAR
  TT: JMCCAR; JMCCAR MAIL - NON-EXISTENT DIRECTORY
» :LISP

  LISP 2154
» Alloc? n
…
  *

» (+ 7 1)
  10

» ^Z
» 50107)   XCT 11   :LOGOUT
```

Remember to exit Lisp and `:LOGOUT` when you're done; if you don't do
this the terminal might be left in its logged-in state for the next
user that connects.

You may find David Moon's [*Maclisp Reference Manual*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Moon) to be
a helpful reference while using this.

Comment: Looks great!  Except for this version of Maclisp, the "Pitmanual" is probably more appropriate: http://maclisp.info/pitmanual/

Comment: why does (+ 7 1) evaluate to 10?  Is it in octal by default?

Comment: @KevinTroy, yes.

Comment: Note, Maclisp from 1971 may be available in the future.  There's also an undated smaller executable which feels a lot like PDP-6 LISP but runs under ITS.

Answer (score 5):

#### PDP-6 LISP (around 1966)

LISP 1.5 ported to the Project MAC / AI Lab PDP-6 in 1964.  This version is estimated to be from around 1966 and is a binary machine code file found on a DECtape belonging to Peter Samson.  Due to an incompatible PDP-6 instruction, it has been patched to run on a PDP-10.  It can of course also be run unpatched on PDP-6 emulators, of which there are a few.

To run this, download and build http://github.com/PDP-10/its

Then start the PDP-10 emulator.  You will enter DSKDMP which can read, write, and run files from the disk.  Type `LISP` and Enter to start PDP-6 LISP.

```
» $./start
…
   DSKDMP
» LISP
» ALLOC? N
» (PLUS 1 2)
  3
» (CONS T NIL)
  (T)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you first has to decide whether you want Maclisp, or LISP 1.5, or something else.

We do have a copy of PDP-10 Maclisp running on ITS here: http://github.com/PDP-10/its
But it's the latest version from the mid 1980s.  There are older versions archived going back to the early 1970s, but they are not public (yet).

There is also Multics Maclisp; ask multicians about it.

There is the direct predecessor to Maclisp: PDP-6 LISP.  It's also available from the **its** repository linked above.  It runs standalone on a PDP-6 or 10; the file name is @ LISP.

I think LISP 1.5 is available and runs on IBM emulators.

The easiest way to experience Maclisp is to log in on an ITS machine and try it.

Comment: You are welcome to telnet to its.pdp10.se port 10003.  Type `^Z` and then `:LOGIN CJS` or similar to login.  Run Maclisp: `:LISP`.  It will ask `Alloc?`; just type `n`.

Comment: Also on this machine is TECO EMACS, PDP-10 Logo, PDP-11 Logo, Lisp Logo, Greenblatt's chess program MacHack VI, Macsyma, etc.

Comment: I'm open to whatever's easy; I anticipate that this question will have multiple answers for various versions of LISP and various levels of "easy." Building ITS myself seems pretty daunting, but your `its.pdp10.se` is a brilliant solution for my needs. I've added a [community wiki answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13436/7208) giving the steps to log in to that; feel free to edit it as you see fit.

Comment: Sadly SE does not support telnet urls like telnet://its.pdp10.se:10003

Answer (score 3):

#### PDP-1 LISP

Amongst the [SIMH Software Kits](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/software.html) is L. Peter Deutsch's PDP-1
LISP 1.5 implementation. It's quite limited (particularly in terms of
memory) and also reads all numbers in octal, but does at least let you
enter and evaluate basic expressions.

On Linux, install SIMH from your distribution's package repositories,
e.g., `sudo apt-get install simh`. Download [`lispswre.zip`](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/kits/lispswre.zip)
(that's from the "Lisp" link on the Kits page above) and unpack it.
`lisp_doc.txt` contains instructions.

You need not compile the assembler and assemble the source; the
included `lisp.rim` is the same output you would have generated
anyway.

Start the emulator with the `pdp1` command and follow the instructions
in §3 of `lisp_doc.txt` to set up the initial machine state. After the
final `c` (continue) command you will not be presented with a prompt,
but you can type Lisp expressions to be evaluated. Remember that
newlines are ignored; typing a space (`▒` in sample input below) after
the final closing paren is what triggers evaulation.

Most errors will halt the machine; when this happens you can continue
with the `c` command:

```
(puls 7 1)▒

HALT instruction, PC: 000005 (STF6)
sim> c
(plus 7 1)▒
10
```

When you're done, <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> will exit back to the `sim>`
prompt where you can use the `q` command to exit. To start again from
your saved machine state (created during the setup above), start the
simulator with `pdp1` and at the `sim>` prompt use the command `get
lisp.sav` followed by `c`.

The [*SIMH Users' Guide*](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/pdf/simh_doc.pdf) contains further details about using
SIMH.